# Light Bulb Button With CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create light bulb button and got  following solution that some what similar to my need but its CSS is very complex and it requires complex javascript too. Is not there a way  to create a simple light bulb button of small size like `W: 50px, H:50px`. That got `on` on click and off on click (Toggle) . Can't we simply do it on glyph icon or awesome font icon?

http://cssdeck.com/labs/light-bulb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/rjah53de) example that I made for you.

The first element that came to mind which has its own toggleable state is a checkbox. You can utilise its `:checked` pseudo-selector to change the style depending on the state of the checkbox.

Since you cannot add a background image to the checkbox itself, I made use of the `label` element which will toggle the checkbox' state when clicked. To style the label differently based on the checkbox' state, I used an [adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) (`+`) to create a rule for the single label following the checkbox.

**Edit**: I updated the example to fix Chrome's whining about the image's MIME type.

**E2:** Although it's out of the scope of your question, if you wished to run some JavaScript when the click happens, you can do something similar to this:

```js
bulb.onclick = function(ev) {
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log('the lightbulb is now on');
    } else {
        console.log('the lightbulb is now off');
    }
};
```

Demonstration [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/l6evxf5a).

**E3**: As mentioned in the comments, pre-loading the "on" image might be a good idea.

- You could use a data URI<sup>[[1]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)</sup><sup>[[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/data_URIs)</sup> to "embed" the image into the CSS, like [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/mhdpjzvc). Although, this method can be slower.
- You could use an image sprite to hold all of the icons you'll need, and upon click, change the `background-position`, like [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xlad1zln).

**E4**: [Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/t1ovnwis) is a way to accomplish the bulb toggle without using a checkbox.

**E5**: [Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/mociintz) is an example using FontAwesome. However, FontAwesome does not include an icon for a lit lightbulb, so I just changed the colour of the text (which doesn't look very nice). Using JavaScript, I changed the `color` property of the element's `style` object. You could instead toggle a CSS class or combine this with the checkbox example.

**E6**: [Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/fqu9tlev) is an example of using FontAwesome in combination with the checkbox example.

**E7**: [Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jovodyni) is a fun example that utilises CSS3 transitions to ease between the two `color`s.

Comment: Try using a sprite or at least preloading the second image.

Comment: Here is a preloading jQuery snippet. Borrowed from SO. http://jsfiddle.net/dJwDg/1/

Comment: Thanks, it solves my question, but can it be done in a same way using glyph icon or awesome font icon? I saw you used images, I am talking aboutdoing it with font

Comment: Thanks spooky you are awesome!! You gave one of the awesome and best answer to the questions I asked  so far...

Comment: @user2304394 I have added another example.